# Remove isotope.js filter, setting it to filter:all on click

Tags: javascript, jquery, onclick, jquery-isotope

## Problem

I'm using `isotope.js` to sort a 60 hockey players. Clicking the button the first time adds a class of `is-active` and arranges the players in order, but clicking it a second time should remove the class of `is-active` the sort and filter back so that I can see all 60 players again.

**When I click the buttons for First Name, Hometown and Games Played, they do not go back to showing all the players `filter:all` when the `is-active` class is removed**

### scripts.js (Snippet)

```
    $(".btn--list").on("click", function(){
        $(".btn--list").not(this).addClass("not-selected");

        // Decade
        if ($(this).hasClass("btn--1960 is-selected")) {
            $grid.isotope({filter: ".year--1960"});
            $(".none").show();
            $(".btn--all").removeClass("is-selected");
        } else if ($(this).hasClass("btn--1970 is-selected")) {
            $grid.isotope({filter: ".year--1970"});
            $(".btn--all").removeClass("is-selected");
        } else if ($(this).hasClass("btn--1980 is-selected")) {
            $grid.isotope({filter: ".year--1980"});
            $(".btn--all").removeClass("is-selected");
        } else if ($(this).hasClass("btn--1990 is-selected")) {
            $grid.isotope({filter: ".year--1990"});
            $(".btn--all").removeClass("is-selected");
        } else if ($(this).hasClass("btn--2000 is-selected")) {
            $grid.isotope({filter: ".year--2000"});
            $(".btn--all").removeClass("is-selected");
        } else if ($(this).hasClass("btn--2010 is-selected")) {
            $grid.isotope({filter: ".year--2010"});
            $(".btn--all").removeClass("is-selected");

        // Position
    } else if ($(this).hasClass("btn--goalie is-selected")) {
        $grid.isotope({filter: ".player--goalie"});
        $(".btn--all").removeClass("is-selected");
        $(".not--goalie").css({
            "display": "none",
            "height": "0px"
        });
    } else if ($(this).hasClass("btn--defencemen is-selected")) {
        $grid.isotope({filter: ".player--defencemen"});
        $(".btn--all").removeClass("is-selected");
    } else if ($(this).hasClass("btn--forward is-selected")) {
        $grid.isotope({filter: ".player--forward"});
        $(".btn--all").removeClass("is-selected");

        // Sort by
    } else if ($(this).hasClass("btn--name is-selected")) {
        $grid.isotope({ sortBy: "name" });
        $(".btn--all").removeClass("is-selected");
    } else if ($(this).hasClass("btn--hometown is-selected")) {
        $grid.isotope({ sortBy: "hometown" });
        $(".btn--all").removeClass("is-selected");
    } else if ($(this).hasClass("btn--gamesp is-selected")) {
        $grid.isotope({ sortBy: "gamesPlayed" });
        $(".btn--all").removeClass("is-selected");

    // `.not--goalie`
    } else if ($(this).hasClass("btn--goals is-selected")) {
        $grid.isotope({ sortBy: "goals" });
        $(".btn--all").removeClass("is-selected");
        $grid.isotope({ filter: ".player--defencemen, .player--forward" })
    } else if ($(this).hasClass("btn--assists is-selected")) {
        $grid.isotope({ sortBy: "assists" });
        $(".btn--all").removeClass("is-selected");
        $grid.isotope({ filter: ".player--defencemen, .player--forward" })
    } else if ($(this).hasClass("btn--points is-selected")) {
        $grid.isotope({ sortBy: "points" });
        $(".btn--all").removeClass("is-selected");
        $grid.isotope({ filter: ".player--defencemen, .player--forward" })
    } else if ($(this).hasClass("btn--penalty is-selected")) {
        $grid.isotope({ sortBy: "penaltyMinutes" });
        $(".btn--all").removeClass("is-selected");
        $grid.isotope({ filter: ".player--defencemen, .player--forward" })

    // These goalie buttons have the correct behaviour
    } else if ($(this).hasClass("btn--goalsagainst is-selected")) {
        $grid.isotope({ filter: ".player--goalie"});
        $grid.isotope({ filter: "goalsAgainst" });
        $(".btn--all").removeClass("is-selected");
    } else if ($(this).hasClass("btn--savepercent is-selected")) {
        $grid.isotope({ filter: ".player--goalie"});
        $grid.isotope({ filter: "savePercentage" });
        $(".btn--all").removeClass("is-selected");
    } else if ($(this).hasClass("btn--shutouts is-selected")) {
        $grid.isotope({ filter: ".player--goalie"});
        $grid.isotope({ filter: "shutouts" });
        $(".btn--all").removeClass("is-selected");
    } else {
        $(".btn--list").not(this).removeClass("not-selected");
        $grid.isotope({ filter: '*' });
        $(".btn--all").addClass("is-selected");
        $(".none").hide();
        $(".not--goalie").css({
            "display": "block",
            "height": "100%",
            "padding-top": "12px",
        });
    }
});
```

### index.html

```
<ul>
                <li><h2>Filters</h2></li>
                <li class="filter--all"><button class="btn--list btn--all is-selected">Select All</button></li>

                <li><h2>Decade</h2></li>
                <li><button class="btn--list btn--1960">1960s</button></li>
                <li><button class="btn--list btn--1970">1970s</button></li>
                <li><button class="btn--list btn--1980">1980s</button></li>
                <li><button class="btn--list btn--1990">1990s</button></li>
                <li><button class="btn--list btn--2000">2000s</button></li>
                <li><button class="btn--list btn--2010">2010s</button></li>

                <li><h2>Position</h2></li>
                <li><button class="btn--list btn--goalie">Goalie</button></li>
                <li><button class="btn--list btn--defencemen">Defenceman</button></li>
                <li><button class="btn--list btn--forward">Forward</button></li>

                <li><h2>Other</h2></li>
                <li><button class="btn--list btn--name">First Name</button></li>
                <li><button class="btn--list btn--hometown">Hometown</button></li>
                <li><button class="btn--list btn--gamesp">Games Played</button></li>
                <li class="not--goalie not--goals"><button class="btn--list btn--goals">Goals</button></li>
                <li class="not--goalie not-assists"><button class="btn--list btn--assists">Assists</button></li>
                <li class="not--goalie not-points"><button class="btn--list btn--points">Points</button></li>
                <li class="not--goalie not-penalty"><button class="btn--list btn--penalty">Penalty Minutes</button></li>
                <li><button class="btn--list btn--goalsagainst">Goals Against <span class="is-highlighted">*</span></button></li>
                <li><button class="btn--list btn--savepercent">Save Percentage <span class="is-highlighted">*</span></button></li>
                <li><button class="btn--list btn--shutouts">Shutouts <span class="is-highlighted">*</span></button></li>
            </ul>
```